# Google Analytics event tracking

Tags: google-analytics, universal-analytics

In the below code I want to added word say video name "XYZ" that should concatenate with Play. 
I have code in which events are getting tracked if I don't concatenate video name.

```
       ga('send', 'event', 'Play', 'pause', 'completed');
```

Can anybody suggest how can I concatenate the video name with Play  in ga(..) code.

Answer (score 1):

It's just Javscript, so you can put:

```
var videoName = 'Cookie Monster';
ga('send', 'event', 'Play-' + videoName, 'pause', 'completed');
```

If you use the Google Analytics Debugger (Chrome Extension), it'll confirm the code runs when it says: *Running command: ga("send", "event", "Play-Cookie Monster", "pause", "completed")*

Answer (score 0):

Sameer, to get the name of the video, using the YouTube API, you can implement the answer in this question: [Youtube API and tracking embedded video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33872462/youtube-api-and-tracking-embedded-video/33885166#33885166)

Hope I've helped you.

Regards, 
Vítor Capretz